# How to scrape stock moment data from Online web Trading Platform

Tags: python, data-mining, web-scraping

I recently started a Data Analysis project that involves data relating to stock market prices (i.e currency pair information). An example is AUD/CAD trade. I wish to scrape 1-minute price details from a Trading Platform, and I'm focusing on [quotex.io](https://quotex.io) in particular. So in [quotex.io](https://quotex.io) on the qxbroker web page which you can easily see if you create a demo account, whenever you hover over an increase or decrease in trade price more details show up at the bottom left, which include

- Open
- Close
- High
- Low

It looks like this
[image]

I want to scrape the following data sets boxed in red, for the past 24 hours of any starting point. If you inspect the page just like i did, you'll see the trade price chart is being loaded on a canvas and it seems the stats for the prices and all are coming from a javascript code and none of the information is static, so information therefore cannot be accessed. Plus it seems there are also tons of security features.

Is it possible to get around this and still have access to the four different attributes for the prices per minute?

Comment: You could just use their API: https://lu-yi-hsun.github.io/quotexapi/

Comment: Okay. Thanks, I didn't know about that. I'll check it out